# What is the correct return of PyObject_CallObject in the presence of a Python exception?

Tags: python, c

All the examples I can find check the return value against a NULL pointer, and yet in our code we are receiving a valid pointer.  We know an exception has occurred because we have written to a log file before and after the failing line.

When we look at the return value it says "NoneType": `returnValue->ob_type->tp_name`.

Comment: The call returned the `None` object in that case, and not NULL, indicating that there is no exception as far as that call is concerned. Whatever method you called could perhaps have handled the exception (like a `try:`/`except` handler would in Python code)?

Comment: We end up in the `except:` handler and dump a message towards that fact

fo.write("exception being throw, return NUll\n")
            return None

Comment: So you handled the exception already in your own `except:`; that *clears* the exception; you need to `raise` it again in that case.

Comment: Excellent that's what was wrong, can you submit that as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call returned the None object in that case, and not NULL, indicating that there is no exception as far as that call is concerned.

If whatever you called used a `try:`/`except` handler, then the exception has already been caught and cleared; that is the purpose of such a handler. If you need the exception to propagate further up the stack, re-raise it:

```
try:
    # ...
except SomeException as e:
    # log information about `e`
    raise
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately for me I didn't write the Python code so we are not sure whether the writer intended to swallow the exception or not.  The call fails to complete, but we don't know if this is an error

The person who wrote it is hard to get hold of, hopefully when we finally track him down we can get the intention of the code.